# Htaccess Redirect Exception for Directory

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, redirect

I have the following code in my htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^site-test.net$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://site-test.net/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^site-test2.net$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^wp-admin/.*$ - [L]
```

What I'm trying to do is get a redirect exception so I can access site-test.com/wp-admin without the redirect but doesn't seem to work the redirect does though

Answer (score 0):

Specific rules should precede general rules:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^wp-admin/.*$ - [L,S=1]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^site-test.net$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://site-test.net/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: @CableGuy Try now. The next rule should get skipped.

Comment: still doesn't here's the thing I'm actually trying to redirect from the first site-test.net I've edited the question to show the redirect